# R circlize: Adjust sector size to total prevalence instead of combination frequency in Circos plot

Tags: r, circlize, circos

I would like to draw a circos plot showing (i) all combinations in a sample through links (ii) each sector length being proportional to total frequency in the sample.
How can I draw a circos plot using the circlize-package for that?

Here is an example of my dataset:

```r
circos_df <- data.frame(
     from = c("C", "D", "D", "D", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
              "A", "F", "F", "B", "B", "B", "B"),
     to = c("E", "F", "C", "E", "B", "D", "F", "C", 
            "E", "C", "E", "D", "F", "C", "E"),
     value = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 0, 1),
     total_freq = c(4, 6, 6, 6, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 26, 26, 4, 4, 4, 4),
     normalized_freq = c(0.1538462, 0.2307692, 0.2307692, 0.2307692, 
                         0.4615385, 0.4615385, 0.4615385, 0.4615385,
                         0.4615385,1.0000000, 1.0000000, 0.1538462,
                         0.1538462, 0.1538462, 0.1538462 ))
```

When I then run the following code, I receive a circos plot with sector size proportional to combination frequency:

```r
# Create a Circos plot
chordDiagram(
  x = circos_df[, c("from", "to", "normalized_freq")],
  preAllocateTracks = list(track.height = 0.1),
  annotationTrackHeight = c(0.02, 0.1),
  annotationTrack = c("name", "grid"),
  direction.type = "arrows",
  #annotationTrackMargin = c(0.1, 0.1),
  #annotationTrackBackground = "transparent"
)
```

However, I was not able to create sectors with the length representing the total frequency of each letter.          I have tried to draw the sectors manually using circos.initalize and circos.rect, however this did not work out or did not include the combination links anymore. I am new to R and could not find an answer in previous posts, so I would be very happy about any suggestions, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to `uncount` your data frame according to total frequency. This will duplicate each row an appropriate amount, meaning that the sectors will have the correct weighting applied:

```r
library(circlize)

chordDiagram(
  x = tidyr::uncount(circos_df, total_freq)[, c("from", "to")],
  grid.col = RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(6, 'Set1'),
  preAllocateTracks = list(track.height = 0.1),
  annotationTrackHeight = c(0.02, 0.1),
  annotationTrack = c("name", "grid"),
  direction.type = "arrows"
)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!I think I described the problem incorrectly as this one now shows the links of total_freq. I have a sample dataset of 55 patients in which total_freq represents the absolute number of patients who have a certain pathogene A-F. "From" and "to" represent the pathogene combinations for each patient and "value" the number of these combinations. What I was thinking of was something like this plot: https://www.molecularecologist.com/2014/12/11/migration-routes-as-circos-plots-in-r/  where the sectors length represents total_freq and the links "value" .Is this possible?

Comment: @a_c_b I'm not sure I understand. The total frequency applies to _combinations_ of pathogenes, but if we add up total_frequency, there are more than 55 combinations found in your data. If I understand you correctly, this means that some patients must have more than one combination of pathogenes. The data frame you have included does not allow calculation of the absolute number of pathogenes, since some pathogenes may be counted multiple times in a given patient, but we don't know which. How would you decide how long to make the grids? Might it be better to represent this as a network graph?

Comment: I think it will be best to use the graph as suggested by you then, thank you.